# Functions of complex variable and its differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

w=f(z)   (complex function)
w=u +iv (u, v are funtions of x and y)
How to find dw/dz in polar form?
Can someone please explain me the chain rule expansion involved in this
The derivative should be equal to partial differential of w in terms of r, theta and x

and z=re^(itheta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The total differential of $w=f(z)=:f(x,y)=u(x,y)+i(v,x)$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> df &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\\
> &=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)dx + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)dy\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

With $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}
=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\\
&=\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\tag{2}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}
=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\
&=\sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
and similarly with $v(x,y)$ instead of $u(x,y)$.

We obtain with $x=x(r,\theta)=r\cos \theta$ and $y=y(r,\theta)=r\sin\theta$
\begin{align*}
dx&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} dr+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}d\theta
=\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta\tag{4}\\
dy&=\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} dr+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}d\theta
=sin\theta\,dr+r\cos\theta\,d\theta\tag{5}\\
\end{align*}

> Putting (2) - (5) into (1) we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{df}&\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)dx + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)dy}\\
> &=\left(\cos\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right.\\
> &\qquad\left.+i\left(\cos\theta\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\sin \theta\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}\right)\right)\left(\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta\right)\\
> &\quad+\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\cos\theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right.\\
> &\qquad\left.+i\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\cos \theta\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}\right)\right)\left(\sin\theta\,dr+r\cos\theta\,d\theta\right)\\
> &=1\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}dr+0\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}dr
> +0\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}d\theta+1\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}d\theta\\
> &\quad+i\left(1\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}dr+0\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}dr
> +0\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}d\theta+1\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}d\theta\right)\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}\right)dr+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}\right)d\theta}
> \end{align*}
>   In (6) we use $\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta=1$ (factor $1$) and observe that terms cancel (factor $0$).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...but thank you for the solution.

Comment: @user552556: You're welcome. Recall you might accept an answer if it fits your needs.

Comment: sorry iam new to this!

Comment: @user552556: No worries, thanks. :-)